# How to edit the text of a MacFamilyTree 7 Narrative Report for Event Types

Tags: macfamilytree

I use MacFamilyTree 7.5 as my primary software and I have been generating narrative reports for people recently and something about the wording of the reports has been bugging me and I would like to edit it.

I have been able to edit the templates in other applications, but have so far not figured out how to do it in MacFamilyTree 7. I entered a support case with them and I got the usual "we will review it for consideration for future enhancement".

[image]

The main issue I have is the wording on the "Residence event" field and how it says "moved to" for each event. In this example I want it to state "resided in" as it would make more sense and also not communicate incorrect information as it lists it currently, it implies the person moved to the location on a particular day, and moved there repeatedly each census year which I record the date of the exact day of the census form in which they appear.

I have expanded done a "Show Package Contents" on the application but not yet found where this text or the map of even type to text is. This may be hard coded out of header and other text format someplace but there is a lot of information in the exposed files; I just haven't gone through them yet and hoping someone else has already perhaps worked through this issue.

> Note: *Unless you know what you are doing, please do not edit or open files inside of your application or you may have to delete MacFamilyTree and re-install it, or even worse lead to data corruption*.

Comment: The reports are dull, they are trying to create "stories" from the limited possibilities of Gedcom files. I suppose it is a design decision, as it seems to be widely believed among website/application creators that genealogists want easy consumed content from limited data. I searched the package without success as well.

Comment: @lejonet People are used to seeing the nicely formatted report out of Family Tree Maker report that does something similar and the narrative is the closest to it I have seen in MacFamilyTree so the reason I am trying to use it.

Comment: @lejonet genealogists don't want easy consumed content from limited data.  "**Lay people**" want easy consumed content from limited data.

Answer (score 3):

The text of parts of MacFamilyTree reports is located at:
MacFamilyTree7.app/Contents/Frameworks/MacFamilyTreeCore.framework/Versions/A/Resources/en.lproj

Edit file CoreStatisticsDiagram.strings or others if you need (inside others files you can search a text of program items, for example - reports and diagram names and much of others). But do backups before any corrections!

Comment: Евгений Харюшин, welcome. I'm not sure if or how this answers the question, so if you can edit it to clarify using the [edit] button below your answer, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm sorry. I do not speak English so much that I would describe the process of editing a text file in eloquent detail. In the issue was a question were is a text of parts of MacFamilyTree reports in the package. I pointed to this.

Comment: No worries, I have edited your answer slightly to make this clearer - and removed my downvote now I understand. If I've changed your meaning incorrectly please feel free to make further edits.